# Saving Files in asp.net server

Tags: asp.net, file-io

i have built an admin panel where admin uploads images to server(they are actualy images of products)

at first i named them acording to my ProductObject.ID so when admin uploaded image to product with a id of 45 the image would be named 45_1 the second picture 45_2

but now i want to change it because when adding images to existing product it works great but creating new product with images couses problems because there is no product id while saving the images

so what i wanna do is every time admin saves image to server, make the program to give unique number to it and keep these numbers(23423.jpg) in a List and save this List to a file

what i wanna know is how can i save that list to a file and after that read it so i know the image name is unique

Comment: Images uploaded by the user should be saved in the database, period!

Comment: i only save the path in database but i dont want to search the whole database to check if the file name is unique i want to save every image name in a string List then save it to a file then read it reference it to a list update it save it again ...

Comment: You are wrong :) User files belong in the database where all user data belongs. Of course you may hit a scaling problem if you are developing YouTube but if you were in fact developing YouTube you wouldn't be asking how to solve this problem on SO :)

Comment: its a e-commerce site and our databases are pretty big already and i have been instructed to include only paths in database.This way or that way i need to it without putting the images in database.An idea struck me i am thinking i can keep file paths in data base and read the last one convert it to int add +1 to it and accept it as my new file name or i might use Guid.

Comment: I understand. This is why I am making a comment and not answering your question. You can store the files in a single folder with names generated as guids and add the path in the database. Of course if the user stops the process after uploading the images you will have non-referenced images on the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that you have unique IDs you should use Guids. You can add the product identifier before that if you prefer:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
String filename = productId + "_" + g.ToString();
```

A Guid is **always** unique so you don't need to worry about that. You need however to save the image identifier somewhere for later access (in a database or in a file, as you prefer)

Comment: this seems promising.I will try this out

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using a Guid as stated by @nmat, you could also use `Path.GetTempFileName`. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx)

This would give you a unique filename while you figure out what you want to do with the file.